# Was Gabriel telling the truth about Josh Talley's rôle at Mariner?

Tags: alliance-union, downbelow-station

I just finished re-reading C.J. Cherryh's 1981 novel [*Downbelow Station*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downbelow_Station) for the purpose of teasing this answer out, but couldn't come to a firm conclusion.

*Downbelow Station* begins immediately after Mariner station is blown up by Union saboteurs.
The Earth Company warship *Norway* leads a fleet of refugee ships, in desperate straits, from the wreck of Mariner Station into Pell Station.

*Norway*'s captain Signy Mallory also turns over a Union prisoner that she rescued from interrogation on Mariner — Josh Talley, an armscomper (operates a targeting computer on a warship) born on Cyteen. For various reasons that aren't important to this question, Talley needs to forget what has gone before, and requests Adjustment (a kind of mindwipe reserved for criminals).

This request is granted by Damon Konstantin, but he feels so bad about it that he's always checking on Talley's welfare, beginning the bromance between the two that will drive much of the action.

During the novel, bits of Josh's Adjustment come undone, and someone later tells him that

> Talley's persona as an armscomper is a construct. He's an azi trained into Union Special Services. He's been Adjusted so many times he doesn't know who he is any more — he has to be told by Gabriel, another Union Special Forces operative who had been on Mariner when it all happened, and who is there to do the same thing to Pell.

This begs the question: Was Talley the one who sabotaged Mariner? The circumstances of Mallory's acquisition of Talley suggest he was busy at the time.

Comment: I'd have to go back to be certain, but I'm pretty sure that it never becomes clear - at least to Talley - if he played a role in Mariner's destruction, or how instrumental he was.  Other characters have their own beliefs in the matter, but I don't recall any actual evidence one way or the other.  And Mallory never tells anyone _anything_ she doesn't have to.

Comment: Just a personal theory, not worth an answer; I always thought that the fact Mallory had picked up Talley and _not_ Gabriel meant that Talley was just a stalking horse and Gabriel was the actual saboteur.